# Random object in ruby, need assistence with exception handling

Tags: ruby, object, random, minesweeper

I am attempting to write a minesweeper game for fun. So far I am working on a board and mine object that will eventually get peppered on the board. Currently when I make a 5 X 5 board for testing purposes and load that into my mine object so it can pick a random column row it will error out part of the time. Here is the code, what I run, and the error I am getting:

```
class Board
  attr_accessor :size, :board

  def initialize(size = gets.chomp.to_i)
    @size = size
    @board = (1..@size).map { |x| ["L"] * @size }
  end

  def print_board
    @board.map { |row| puts row.join }
  end
end

class Mine
  attr_accessor :proxi, :row, :col

  def initialize(proxi)
    @proxi = proxi
    @row = Random.rand(1..@proxi.board.length)
    @col = Random.rand(1..@proxi.board[0].length)
    check_position
  end

  def check_position
    if @proxi.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] != "L"
      initialize
    else
      map_position
    end
  end

  def map_position
    @proxi.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] = "*"
  end
end

b = Board.new(5)

=> #<Board:0x000000024cbb50 @size=5, @board=[["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"]]> 

m = Mine.new(b)

 => #<Mine:0x000000024ae9d8 @proxi=#<Board:0x000000024cbb50 @size=5, @board=[["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"]]>, row3, col3 

m = Mine.new(b)

 => #<Mine:0x00000002487888 @proxi=#<Board:0x000000024cbb50 @size=5, @board=[["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["*", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"]]>, row4, col1 

m = Mine.new(b)

 => #<Mine:0x000000024758b8 @proxi=#<Board:0x000000024cbb50 @size=5, @board=[["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["*", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"]]>, row4, col3 

m = Mine.new(b)

 => #<Mine:0x000000024211a0 @proxi=#<Board:0x000000024cbb50 @size=5, @board=[["L", "L", "L", "*", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["*", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"]]>, row1, col4 

m = Mine.new(b)

 => #<Mine:0x000000023b37e0 @proxi=#<Board:0x000000024cbb50 @size=5, @board=[["L", "L", "L", "*", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"], ["*", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["*", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"]]>, row3, col1 

m = Mine.new(b)

 => #<Mine:0x0000000235ed08 @proxi=#<Board:0x000000024cbb50 @size=5, @board=[["L", "L", "L", "*", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "*", "L"], ["*", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["*", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"]]>, row2, col4 

m = Mine.new(b)

 => #<Mine:0x00000002310888 @proxi=#<Board:0x000000024cbb50 @size=5, @board=[["L", "L", "L", "*", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "*", "L"], ["*", "L", "*", "L", "*"], ["*", "L", "*", "L", "L"], ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"]]>, row3, col5 

m = Mine.new(b)

 ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
     from (irb):16:in `initialize'
     from (irb):25:in `check_position'
     from (irb):20:in `initialize'
     from (irb):43:in `new'
     from (irb):43
     from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

So eventually when I feed a new object instance the modified board instance it does not take. I am not sure why this is but was hoping someone could steer me in the right direction so I can move on to automating this. Thank you!

Here is the solution I went with:

```
class Mine
  attr_accessor :proxi, :row, :col

  def initialize(proxi)
    @proxi = proxi
    @row = 0
    @col = 0
    @random = Random.new
    check_position
  end

  def check_position
    if @proxi.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] != "L"
      @row = @random.rand(1..@proxi.board.length)
      @col = @random.rand(1..@proxi.board[0].length)
      check_position
    else
      map_position
    end
  end

  def map_position
    @proxi.board[@row - 1][@col - 1] = "*"
  end
end
```

Comment: In `Mine.map_position` you call `Mine.initialize` without parameter but I think it requires the board, doesn't it? Maybe you should move the randomization funtionalitity out of `initialize` into another method (e.g. `place_mine`) and then call `place_mine' from within `initialize` and `check_position`. By the way: when your board gets crowded you may run into a heap overflow problems since you still have a circular call from `check_position` to `place_mine` to `check_position`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `check_position` method tries to call back to `initialize` if the position is already taken, but fails to pass the required `proxi` parameter.

I think its unwise (if even possible) to re-call the `initialize` method since that's your class's constructor.

I'd prefer to extract the logic related to finding an open position to a set of helper methods. Something like the following will help you get there:

```
private

  def find_open_position
    x = 0
    y = 0

    begin
      x, y = random_position
    while position_taken?(x, y)

    [x, y]
  end

  def random_position
    [Random.rand(1..@proxi.board.length), @col = Random.rand(1..@proxi.board[0].length)]
  end

  def position_taken?(x, y)
    @proxi.board[x - 1][x - 1] != "L"
  end
```

Then your `initialize` need only include

```
 @row, @col = find_open_position
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I went in and changed my init for the mine so it boots up the col and row as int values and a random object instance. I then make my detect method use the random instance to fill the int values and it redoes it if it does not meet the criteria. Thsi way i have all my properties started with the object and I am not re constructing. Thank you sir!